# getDay() in Angular is undefined when data arrives from C#

Tags: c#, angular

I have object whose type is a `Date` in Angular. When I initialize it in Angular like this:

```
d = new Date();
```

and then I do:

```
d.getDay();
```

everything is OK.

But when I got value of d from my server running C#, and then I ask for

```
d.getDay()
```

I got this error:

> d.getDay is not a function

What can I do?

Comment: add reproducible example

Comment: When it comes from C#, it's really a string - you need to first initialize your date again: `d = new Date(value-from-c#).getDay();`

Comment: thanks! you save my day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I write the answer for other people,
the answer was like marc-s said:

```
    new Date(d).getDay()
```

this solved the problem